# Rails cookie not persisting on mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am developing an analytics system that I have a global user id and a session id. I am storing the global user id in a cookie created on my rails server, and the session id I store in a cookie that I create in a browser.

The global user id is set to expire in 2 years, and every time a new request from that user arrives I restart the counter. The same happens with the session id, except that the time is 25 minutes.

What is happening is that in some mobile phones the cookie that I set in my rails server is not persisted. So every time the user navigates to other pages he has the same session id but the user id changes.

What could it be?

Comment: same question as you... someone told me to change to activerecord storage, but seems hacky to me.